# How to specify JDBC URL in spring boot application in case of the MySQL running as a Kubernetes Service?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, hikaricp

I have a java application with maven build. I have provided the k8 service name of the mysql in the application properties of the spring boot application. However, I get error as unknown host and the maven build fails. How do I overcome this?

Application properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mymysqlk8servicename/testdb
```

When I build the application using mvn clean install, the build fails with error as java.net.UnknownHostException.

For the record, I am running the maven build in the master machine of the Kubernetes cluster. Should I run the java application only as a Kubernetes service? Is it possible to just run the java application without deploying in the Kubernetes  cluster?

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
kubectl get service
```

You should be able to see the servicename. Pay attention to the port too.

Comment: Even if I add the port number, I get the same error. I have configured the correct service name.

Comment: @CuteBoy can you ssh into the pod and try connecting to the host/port manually? Something like nc -vz mymysqlk8servicename 3306